# Print Screen using OnSreen Keyboard

Tags: windows-xp, screenshot, screen-capture

My granddad is using the computer and he wants to take screen shots of certain web pages. He uses the Windows PrtScrn through the On-Screen Keyboard.

So, now, he is typing this question on SuperUser and wants to take a screenshot of it.

1. Switches to `On-Screen Keyboard`
2. Clicks on `psc`
3. Launches `MS Paint`
4. Clicks on `Edit` > `Paste`

Now, he gets the following image. [image]

Question: How can he take the screenshot of the Internet Explorer alone.

Additionally, how do you achieve the equivalent of Alt + Prt Scr using On-Screen Keyboard

Comment: He can take the screenshot of IE by focusing on the IE window and using his keyboard. Onscreen Keyboard is holding focus when the screenshot's taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following search in Google:-

`internet explorer add-on screen grab`

There are plenty of freeware applications out there that will allow you to capture the IE window using a mouse and the IE toolbar.

**This one works:**

http://gadgetinspiration.com/blog/easyweb2pic-screen-capture-browser-add-on-for-internet-explorer

called EasyWeb2Pic Pro does exactly what you want. After you have installed it you need to select View > Toolbars > EasyWeb2Pic Pro Toolbar

Answer (score 2):

Move the onscreen keyboard to the side such that it longer covers the IE window.

Then click Alt on the keyboard followed by PrtScrn - this just works as Alt+PrtScreen for me.

Comment: Amit Agarwal: He is taking the screenshot purely from the On-Screen keyboard. So, if I move it to the side so that it no longer convers the IE window, the On-Screen keyboard will also not be visible to me any more.

Comment: He wants to use the onscreen keyboard. Not a physical keyboard. "how do you achieve the equivalent of Alt + Prt Scr using On-Screen Keyboard"

Comment: +1. Why was this down voted? Alt+Printscr is achieved by pressing Alt+Printscr. The OSK remains as it's always in focus by design. Dragging it partially offscreen to minimise the amount shown is the best solution.

Comment: +1 as well.  @RJFalconer is exactly right - this is by design and unfortunately there's really no way around it.  The best thing to do is either A: Make the window non-maximized, so they don't overlap or B: Just suck it up.

Comment: @RJFalconer: It was down voted because it failed to mention that OSK is always in focus by design and nothing can be done about it. I am happy to remove the down vote if it gets edited.

Comment: "OSK is always in focus by design" From what I'm seeing the OSK does not steal focus. [I just used Alt+Print Scr on the OSK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOx2o.png), [see my window layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm7uA.png). [Here's my window layout in Windows XP SP3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRxqe.png) (Though it is true that you can't do this for maximized windows)